# Как объединить 2 массива pandas, по общему столбцу

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe

У меня есть два датафрейма df1 и df2. В обоих два столбца _a и _b. В df1 оба столбца заполнены.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'_a':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3],'_b':[3,4,5,3,3,3,9]})
df1

    _a  _b
0   1   4
1   3   9
2   4   3
3   2   5
```

В df2 заполнен только столбец _a в другом порядке, нужно заполнить столбец _b по аналогии с df1. В итоге должно получится вот так:

```
    _a  _b
0   4   3
1   3   9
2   1   4
3   2   5
```

Подобная функция в есть в Excel, называется ВПР. Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [DataFrame.merge(anotherDF)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

Пример:

```
In [6]: df1
Out[6]:
   _a  _b
0   1   4
1   3   9
2   4   3
3   2   5

In [7]: df2
Out[7]:
   _a
0   4
1   3
2   1
3   2

In [8]: df2 = df2.merge(df1, on='_a', how='left')

In [9]: df2
Out[9]:
   _a  _b
0   4   3
1   3   9
2   1   4
3   2   5
```

`NOTE:` в том случае если в DataFrame'ах присутствуют дубликаты значений в столбце(ах), участвующих в объединении `df.merge()` - сделает декартово произведение (`cartesian product`) для дублированных строк.

---

в том случае если в DataFrame надо подставить значения *только одного столбца* из другого DF - можно воспользоваться методом [Seiries.map()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
In [7]: df2['_b'] = df2['_a'].map(df1.set_index('_a')['_b'])

In [8]: df2
Out[8]:
   _a  _b
0   4   3
1   3   9
2   1   4
3   2   5
```

PS `Seiries.map()` - обычно работает быстрее и требует меньше памяти по сравнению с `DataFrame.merge()`, но позволяет добавить только один столбец.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, это то что нужно. Но после выполнения merge, у меня появилась ошибка MemoryError. Подозреваю что это из-за большого объема массива (более 500000 строк). Что посоветуете, для ее исправления.

Comment: @spectrum, добавил более оптимальный вариант для добавления единственного столбца...